# Angular 2: Querying custom attribute values from ElementRef

Tags: angular

I have a list of images. I bound a custom ID attribute to each  like so:

```
<img #myChildren ... [attr.myId]="item.id" />
```

And in my component the images are queried with @ViewChildren:

```
@ViewChildren( 'myChildren' ) myChildren: QueryList<ElementRef>
```

Given an ElementRef from myChildren, how can I learn the value of its myId attribute?

Comment: It is not an 'angular' way. But you still can do `el: ElementRef; el.nativeElement.getAttribute('myid');`.

Comment: Yeah, that works fine, thanks!